# Adjacent sibling selector not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sliding sidebar without javascript, but I have a problem with an adjacent sibling selector which is not working.

This is my code:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #181918;
  border-left: solid 1px #181918;
}
.sidebar ul li {
  font-family: 'Zona Pro';
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(24, 25, 24, 0.78);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebarToggler {
  display: none;
}
#sidebartoggler + .sidebar {
  top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageWrap">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggler" />
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Settings</li>
      <li>Log out</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="userNameDiv">
    <label for="sidebarToggler">
      Fale1994
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="pageContent">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working OK except the last line of CSS... I tried everything and have no more ideas.

When clicked on `label`, the `checkbox` changes checked/unchecked, and then CSS should set a sidebar attribute 'top' to `500px` if checked. I also tried this with `background-color`, but it is also not working.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "not working." Explicitly say what you *want* to happen and what is happening instead.

Comment: did you check my comment? @Fale1994

Answer (score 2):

2 things you are missing:

- the `:checked` from ckeckbox
- and you have `#sidebartoggler` but CSS is case sensitive, so use `#sidebarToggler`

#### Snippet

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #181918;
  border-left: solid 1px #181918;
}
.sidebar ul li {
  font-family: 'Zona Pro';
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(24, 25, 24, 0.78);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebarToggler {
  display: none;
}
#sidebarToggler:checked + .sidebar {
  top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageWrap">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggler" />
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Settings</li>
      <li>Log out</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="userNameDiv">
    <label for="sidebarToggler">
      Fale1994
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="pageContent">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake I have made. The second one was a problem, and I spent few hours to found a mistake.

Thank you very much

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help! If this fix your issue make sure you mark this answer as accepted for future readers know what was the solution for your the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebartoggler:checked + .sidebar
```

You forgot the `:checked`.

Comment: oh, I have deleted it to try the code without it and then forgot to write it back. But that is not the problem, it is not working with :checked. Sorry